# pyqt4 pixel information on rotated image

Tags: image, pyqt4

I have adapted an image viewer (see code below) to allow me to get pixel information from a loaded image. You load an image using the 'Load image' button, then you can zoom in and out using the scroll wheel, and pan using mouse left click and drag. When you press the button 'Enter pixel info mode', the dragging is disabled (you can still zoom) and clicking on the image will give the pixel coordinate (integer pixel indices) and grayscale value of the pixel.

The problem is that if you rotate the image, by pressing the 'Rotate image' button, using the pixel info button no longer gives the correct pixel info. I imagine that the mapToScene method is not the right thing to use on a rotated image but can find no other way to do it. I have tried various things, such as using toImage() on the rotated pixmap and then replacing the original image with this, but nothing seems to work. What would be the best way to resolve this?

The code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class PhotoViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def fitInView(self):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                         viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self.centerOn(rect.center())
            self._zoom = 0

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif self.hasPhoto():
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.fitInView()
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            if event.delta() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if (self.hasPhoto() and
            self.dragMode() == QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag and
            self._photo.isUnderMouse()):
            self.photoClicked.emit(QtCore.QPoint(event.pos()))
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)        
        self.editPixInfo = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        # Button to rotate image by 10 degrees
        self.btnRotate = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnRotate.setText('Rotate image')
        self.btnRotate.clicked.connect(self.rotateImage)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnRotate)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('pic.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def rotateImage(self):
        self.viewer._photo.setRotation(10)

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        pos = self.viewer.mapToScene(pos)
        # p.s. I realise the following lines are probably a very convoluted way of getting
        # a grayscale value from RGB, but I couldn't make it work any other way I tried
        rot_image = self.viewer._photo.pixmap().toImage().pixel(pos.x(), pos.y())
        colour = QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(rot_image)
        gsval = QtGui.qGray(colour.red(), colour.green(), colour.blue())
        self.editPixInfo.setText('X:%d, Y:%d Grayscale: %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y(), gsval))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the scene coordinates to item coordinates:

```
pos = self.viewer._photo.mapFromScene(self.viewer.mapToScene(pos))
```

Comment: As before (you answered my last question) you have fixed it for me. Out of interest, do you know any good books or tutorials to learn this kind of stuff (pyqt4 image manipulation and drawing/animating in particular). There are so many things I don't know, it feels like I'm groping in the dark. I always find it easier to learn by example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AndrewBirch. I don't have any personal recommendations. The [PyQt Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) has some useful links, but be warned that some of them may be quite old. The [PyQt4 examples](http://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples/graphicsview) also has some graphics demos (based on the ones from the Qt Docs).